# PHP-FPM socket on remote machine

Tags: php, sockets, nginx, server, load-balancing

Is it possible to connect to a remote server running php-fpm (7) using a Unix socket instead of a TCP socket?

All available tutorials are showing either local configuration for socket:

> fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock

or remote using address

```
upstream php-fpm {
    server  10.10.10.1:8000 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=120;
    server  10.10.10.2:8000 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=120;
    # additional servers
}
```

However, I cannot find any information on how to connect to a remote server via socket. How shall I expose it? Via SSH?

Comment: A Unix domain socket can only be used to exchange data between processes executing on the same host operating system. See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) for more.